# Firefox add-on will not display images

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

I have a blank Firefox Add-On I made using the [Getting Started Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_(jpm)). When I run my extension using `jpm run` I observe the following.

If I navigate to any image it appears like this (image is displayed nicely in the centre):

[image]

However, I have the same image store in my extension under: `./data/test.jpg`. When I navigate to `resource://my-addon/data/test.jpg` I get the following blank page:

[image]

The image is there, because if I hover over it in the inspector, it shows:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong, missing something in the docs about rendering images or is there a bug with how images are being rendered from the extension?

Answer (score 0):

Include the `self` and then do

```
console.log(seld.data.url(''))
```

This will give you the id of your addon. It is very likely not `my-addon` it will be something like: `jid1-4GP7z3tkUd3Tzg@jetpack` - so your path to your image will be `resource://jid1-4GP7z3tkUd3Tzg@jetpack/data/test.jpg`.